# How can I install support for qcow2 images for KVM on linux mint 18?

Tags: kvm

I've got KVM (apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst) on linux mint 18. I created a CentOS 7 VM using raw disk format because I couldn't use qcow2 disk image format.
What do I need to install to get qcow2 support?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! It was really just a matter of reading the error message. I had to install `qemu-utils` and restart virt-manager.
Maybe it could be useful for anyone else.